# When executing a .run file in Linux, how to find out what will be installed or how to find out what was installed afterwards?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, installation, executable

I wonder if it's possible to find out in some way what was installed after I ran a .run file under Linux? **Or maybe there is a tool that scans a .run in order to find out whats inside it?**

I need this because I'd like to install the software bundled in this .run with aptitude in order to keep it up to date. But the bundle is just available as a .run file.

Does anyone now how to do the trick?

Comment: This question seems to belong to serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do something like

1. setting up a secure `chroot` (or virtualmachine) environment (Google for that), and install in that.
2. do something like

   ```
   find / > ORIGINAL_STATE -exec ls -lc \{\} \;
   ./INSTALLER.RUN
   find / > AFTER_INSTALL -exec ls -lc \{\} \;
   diff ORIGINAL_STATE AFTER_INSTALL
   ```

Comment: This won't find out about any files that have been changed.

Comment: Well, now it can (if the installer doesn't trick with the date etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of .run files (or other binary installation files) I have seen are regular scripts with a binary part in them. This means you can open them with a text editor and inspect the first few lines (open with `less` rather than a gui editor so it doesn't get stuck on the binary part).

Comment: In my case the .run is solely binary, an ELF. So no chance to get infos not even with `strings`.